# Pass payload from one saga to another saga

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-saga, saga

I need to pass payload from `fromSaga` to `toSaga`. The problem is it seems that `toSaga` does not get the payload. However, if I dispatch an action via useEffect, `toSaga` gets the payload. My observation is that, if you dispatch an action from `fromSaga` it skips the action creator and goes directly to `toSaga`. As a result, no payload is sent to `toSaga`. Here's the real code:

```
const fetchTokens = function*(action: any) {
    try {
        const userCreds: any = toSnakeCase(action.payload) // action.payload is undefined here
        const response: any = yield call(fetchTokensApi, userCreds)

        if (response.status === 200) {
            const data: any = response.data.data
            const tokens: Tokens = {
               accessToken: data.access_token,
               refreshToken: data.refresh_token,
               expiry: extractExpiry(data.access_token),
           }
           yield put({ type: types.FETCH_TOKENS_SUCCESS, tokens})
       }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: types.FETCH_TOKENS_FAILURE, error })
    }
}

export const fetchTokensSaga = function*() {
   yield takeLatest(types.FETCH_TOKENS, fetchTokens)
}

const validateAccessToken = function*() {
    try {
        const tokens: Tokens = yield select(tokensSelector)

        if (!tokens) {
            yield put({ type: types.FETCH_TOKENS, USER_CREDS })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: types.FETCH_TOKENS_FAILURE, error })
    }
}
```

In `validateAccessToken`, `fetchTokensSaga` is called via:

```
yield put({ type: types.FETCH_TOKENS, USER_CREDS })
```

`fetchTokens` should then get the `USER_CREDS`. However, it's not the case as `payload` is always `undefined`. What should I do so `fetchTokens` gets the `USER_CREDS` payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're directly dispatching a raw object, not using an action creator, so you need to put `USER_CREDS` under the payload key:

`yield put({ type: types.FETCH_TOKENS, payload: USER_CREDS })`

If you have an action creator like

```
function fetchTokensActionCreator(userCreds) {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_TOKENS,
    payload: userCreds,
  };
}
```

you can instead do `yield put(fetchTokensActionCreator(USER_CREDS));`

Comment: Isn't calling action creator directly discouraged by saga as it's hard to test?

Comment: Not in my experience, no. The testing docs from redux-saga (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html) show how to test when using action creators (in their example the `changeUI` action creator.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `payload` key when dispatching as you are using `action.payload` within `fetchTokens()`.

```
yield put({
  type: types.FETCH_TOKENS,
  payload: USER_CREDS // add payload
})
```